# Send OpenGL video flux via UDP

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d, udp

It is possible to send the video flux of an OpenGL desktop app via UDP **on Linux** ? I looked up [FBO](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object) and off-screen rendering but I still can't figure out how to extract the video flux and send it.

I'm working with C++ but if you have explanations in others langages go ahead.

Thanks.

My original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424076/send-opengl-video-flux-via-udp) on stack overflow.

Comment: What's your problem exactly? You render a frame into a FBO, extract it from FBO, send it, then repeat with another frame. You also should use some king of codec, because uncompressed video is too heavy.

Comment: My problem was about retrieving each frame and send it via UDP but now it's ok, I understood how to do it. Now I need to render off screen with FBO but I don't know how to, so I'll search. If you have links about it i'd be happy !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a intra-network cross-post. Please post your question on only one SE site.

Answer (score 1):

I understood by myself how to retrieve the frame rendered and now I have this method :

```
void Renderer::getVideoStream(){
    glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);

    int width = m_window->width();
    int height = m_window->height();

    vector< unsigned char > buf( width * height * 3 );

    glPixelStorei( GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
    glReadPixels( 0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &buf[0] );

    // compress the image

    // send it via UDP
}
```

It works good with screenshots and I should be able to send it via UDP but I don't understand how to use it with **FBO** so I'll do some search and eventually post another question about it in an other thread.